# Чтение СМС модулем Sim900 arduino mega

Tags: arduino, sms

У меня есть модуль Sim900 модели s2-1040s-z1k18 и Arduino Mega 2560. Мне нужно узнать остаток текущего пакета. Ответ приходит в виде СМС. У меня есть такой код:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Serial1.begin(57600);
}

void loop()
{
  delay(100);
  while(Serial.available()) 
  {
    Serial1.write(Serial.read());
  }
  while(Serial1.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(Serial1.read());
  }
}
```

В мониторе порта я указываю такие команды

```
AT
OK

AT+CMGF=1
OK

AT+CUSD=1,"*106#" // узнать остаток пакета у билайн
OK
+CUSD: 0,"04120430044800345660430043F0440043E345500200432002
```

Так же мною была опробована команда

```
AT+CMGL="REC UNREAD"

+CMGL: 4,"REC UNREAD","BeeInfo","","22/07/27,20:49:06+24"
00200432342CDC0435043D002343C0438043D002
```

Как мне расшифровать данные набор символов? Во всех примерах в которых были указаны такие методы текст возвращался в виде текста, а не набора символов. Или как мне иначе узнать остаток пакета? Данные данные мне нужно будет использовать в дальнейшем коде программы.

Comment: Вот тут https://www.developershome.com/sms/cmgrCommand3.asp#26.2.6 есть про похожее кодирование